# How do you directly and automatically import data from a public Tableau dashboard to a PowerBI dashboard

Tags: microsoft-powerbi, dashboard, analysis, tableau

As the title says, I need to scrape data from a public Tableau dashboard and import it directly to a PowerBI dashboard. No middle-men should be involved.